# Typescript: create type that makes sure value is inside array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have object

```
const AllTranslations = {
  ACCEPT: {
    en: "Accept this",
    de: "Akzeptieren"
  },
  UNKNOWN_ERROR: {
    en: "Unexpected error occurred"
  }
};
```

and I have this type
`export type TransKey = keyof typeof AllTranslations;`

I have translate function that receives prop of type TransKey and I want it to throw error if given string does not exist as key in AllTranslations. That works for given code.

Now, I also want typescript to throw error if "en" or "de" is missing, and that can be done if I put type for AllTranslations as Record<string, {en: string, de: string}>. But then the problem is that TransKey type will now actually be just string, and I can pass any string to translate function and it will not complain...

Any solution how to have both? That the translate function complains if there is no given key (e.g. ACCEPT) inside AllTranslations, and also ts complains if en or de is missed inside AllTranslations?

I can get array of keys e.g. ["ACCEPT", "UNKNOWN,ERROR"] with object.keys, but don't know if it's possible to create type that would look like "ACCEPT" | "UNKNOWN_ERROR" automatically

Comment: Please share your work (code) that you have done so far